# How many isomorphisms are there between two cyclic groups of order $n > 0$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, discrete-mathematics, cyclic-groups, group-isomorphism

I'm stuck at this exercise. How can I approach this? I know that an isomorphism is a bijective homomorphism but we can't just count the number of bijections ($n!$), since we can't just assign every element to any other element. We need to work with the generators. A cyclic group of order n has $\phi (n) = |\mathbb Z  ^{*}_{n}|$ generators. And this is where I get stuck. How can I continue from here?

Thank you

Comment: Hint: The image of a generating set under homomorphism is a generating set.

Comment: Hint: an isomorphism must send a generator *to* a generator, so you have an upper bound. Is this also a lower bound?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An homomorphism $\iota$ from $\mathbb{Z}_n$ onto itself is completely determined by the image of $1$, since $1$ generates $\mathbb{Z}_n$. Since you want $\iota$ to be surjective, $\iota(1)$ must be a generator of $\mathbb{Z}_n$ and, as you know, you have $\phi(n)$ choices for that. Therefore, the answer is $\phi(n)$.

Comment: Better asking before editing!

Answer (score 1):

You are making a mistake on the number of generators. But anyway, notice that a morphism from a cyclic group $C_n$ of order $n$ is completely determined by the image of any one of its generators. So let $1\in C_n$ be a generator, where can you map it into the other cyclic group in such a way that you get a homomorphism of groups?